# Setting up development and production environment for a Liferay project

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I received a Liferay project source code and asked to set up a development and production environment for it. The project is in Liferay EE but client license expired so it need to be ready with CE till further notice.

I have looked in Liferay website but they mostly explain how to created a new project, but no how to set it and import the project.

So far I already import the project (as a General Java project because even after I created the "build.username.properties" file if kept failing) but still lots of errors are coming up.

I am using: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.2.10 EE GA1, Eclipse Mars with plugin and Java 8.

EDIT: My question is which should be the order and what have I install in order to ste up the environments.

Comment: And what is your question? Without the exact error messages it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Which application server will you use? You could download a liferay portal bundle with tomcat and start working on it.

Comment: step #1: elaborate on "lots of errors are coming up". If you are (or were) an EE customer, the license is typically unlimited in time, just the support runs out - unless you just used a time-limited trial license. Check if you actually get hold of an EE license file - that will be easier than backporting to CE